Trying to export tables to .csv file: Procedure Fails
I'm on Oracle SQL Developer; I got a procedure from the internet and adapted it to my environment. The CREATE script is the following:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dump_table_to_csv (
    tab_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_dir IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'EJEMPLO',
    p_filename IN OUT VARCHAR2
) IS
    
    Vfile   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; --STREAM para escribir[/leer] en fichero con UTL_FILE
    cursor1 integer DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;   --CURSOR que llevará a cabo la query
    col_value   VARCHAR2(4000);             --Almacenará los valores en cada columna aqui
    c_status    INTEGER;                    --Guardará el estado de la ejecución de la query especificada
    query       VARCHAR2(1000) DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM ' || tab_name;    --Será la consulta en sí que queremos llevar a cabo
    n_cols      NUMBER := 0;                --Numero de columnas para saber cuantas veces vamos a iterar por el res. de la query
    str_separator   VARCHAR2(1);            --Separador para el fichero de salida de CSV
    desc_tab_var    DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;      --Variable reservada del paquete DBMS_SQL, que tiene la descripción de la tabla a explorar.
BEGIN
    IF (p_filename IS NULL) THEN
        p_filename := tab_name || '.csv';
    END IF;

    Vfile := UTL_FILE.fopen(p_dir, p_filename, 'W');
    EXECUTE immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format="dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss"';
    
    DBMS_SQL.parse(cursor1, query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE); --especificamos la query deseada, y el especificador NATIVE (1) para tratar la query de manera normal sin cambios extra
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursor1, n_cols, desc_tab_var);
    
    FOR i IN 1..n_cols LOOP
        UTL_FILE.put(Vfile, str_separator || '''' || desc_tab_var(i).col_name || '''');
        dbms_sql.define_column(cursor1, col_value, 4000); --Cursor , posición (columna_a_leer), num. de columnas (?)
        str_separator := ','; --poner coma en el separador para límites entre valores/columna y columna
    END LOOP;
    
    UTL_FILE.new_line(Vfile); --insertar salto de línea
    
    c_status := DBMS_SQL.execute(cursor1); --poner en marcha la query, y registrar su proceso en la variable c_status
    
    WHILE (dbms_sql.fetch_rows(cursor1) > 0) LOOP
        str_separator := ''; --limpiar el serparador antes de empezar a recoger valor de cada fila
        FOR i IN 1..n_cols LOOP
            DBMS_SQL.column_value(cursor1, i, col_value); --recoger valor de la columna
            UTL_FILE.put(Vfile, str_separator || col_value); --escribir en fichero el valor + separador
            str_separator := ',';    --actualizar separador a una coma, de nuevo
        END LOOP;
        UTL_FILE.new_line(Vfile); --Salto de linea
    END LOOP;
    
    --cerramos tanto el cursor, como el STREAM de escritura del fichero
    DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(cursor1);
    UTL_FILE.fclose(Vfile);
    
    --Al terminar...
    --...volver a cambiar el formato de fecha (NLS) al valor por defecto
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT="dd-MON-yy"';
    
    --...Y si ocurre cualquier excepción, antes de salir hacerlo también, y levantar (RAISE) una excepción como alarma
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT="dd-MON-yy"';
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20928, SQLERRM);
            END;
            
            
END;
/

The output is:
"Error que empieza en la línea: 96 del comando :
DECLARE
    path_filename VARCHAR2(100) := 'regions.csv';
BEGIN
    DUMP_TABLE_TO_CSV('hr.regions', 'EJEMPLO', path_filename);
END;
Informe de error -
ORA-20928: ORA-01007: la variable no está en la lista de selección
ORA-06512: en "HR.DUMP_TABLE_TO_CSV", línea 59
ORA-06512: en línea 4"

I don't understand why it's asking me about a variable, it's not in any SELECT list apart from the IS declaring block... Please help, thanks!
I tried changing the parameters to no avail.
